# Error: VECTORSZ is too small

Tags: concurrency, formal-verification, model-checking, promela, spin

I am new to working with Promela and in particular SPIN. I have a model which I am trying verify and can't understand SPIN's output to resolve the problem.

Here is what I did:

```
spin -a untitled.pml
gcc -o pan pan.c
./pan
```

The output was as follows:

```
pan:1: VECTORSZ is too small, edit pan.h (at depth 0)
pan: wrote untitled.pml.trail

(Spin Version 6.4.5 -- 1 January 2016)
Warning: Search not completed
+ Partial Order Reduction

Full statespace search for:
  never claim           - (none specified)
  assertion violations  +
  acceptance   cycles   - (not selected)
  invalid end states    +

State-vector 8172 byte, depth reached 0, errors: 1
    0 states, stored
    0 states, matched
    0 transitions (= stored+matched)
    0 atomic steps
hash conflicts:         0 (resolved)
```

I then ran SPIN again to try to determine the cause of the problem by examining the trail file. I used this command:

```
spin -t -v -p untitled.pml
```

This was the result:

```
using statement merging
spin: trail ends after -4 steps
#processes: 1
( global variable dump omitted )
-4: proc  0 (:init::1) untitled.pml:173 (state 1)
1 process created
```

According to this output (as I understand it), the verification is failing during the "init" procedure. The relevant code from within untitled.pml is this:

```
init {
  int count = 0;
  int ordinal = N;

  do  // This is line 173
    :: (count < 2 * N + 1) ->
```

At this point I have no idea what is causing the problem since to me, the "do" statement should execute just fine.

Can anyone please help me in understanding SPINs output so I can remove this error during the verification process? The model does produce the correct output for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply ignore the `trail` file in this case, it is not relevant at all.

The error message

```
pan:1: VECTORSZ is too small, edit pan.h (at depth 0)
```

tells you that the size of directive `VECTORSZ` is **too small** to successfully verify your model.

By default, `VECTORSZ` has size `1024`.

To fix this issue, try compiling your verifier with a larger `VECTORSZ` size:

```
spin -a untitled.pml
gcc -DVECTORSZ=2048 -o run pan.c
./run
```

If `2048` doesn't work too, try some more *(increasingly larger)* values.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly! I had to increase it a few orders of magnitude but eventually, it was successful :)